# Sequelize, update timestamp if older when upserting new data

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

Sequelize/ MySQL table:
`id: integer,`
`timestamp: Date`
`anotherField: string`

I am upserting with a new document:

```
{ id: alreadyInTheDatabase, timestamp: reallyOldValue, anotherField: "newValue" }
```

I need to update `timestamp` but only if it is older (smaller) then the one upserting the database, anotherField needs to be always updated.
What is the best approach for it?

Thank you! :-)

Comment: **LEAST()** is your goal. use **yourfield = LAST( yourfield, newval)**

Comment: Can you provide an example please?